# Problem with creating laravel project - do not run Composer as root/super user

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, root

I have a problem with creating new laravel project. I installed Composer according to instruction but all the time when I try to create new project in laravel I have error like this:

> Do not run Composer as root/super user! See
>   https://getcomposer.org/root for details Installing laravel/laravel
>   (v5.5.28)
>     - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.5.28): Loading from cache Created project in /mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/laravel
>
> > @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');" Loading composer repositories with package information Updating
> >     dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be
> >     resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.9 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.8 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.13 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.12 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.11 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.10 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.4.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.4.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.4.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.4.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.4.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.3.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.3.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.2.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.2.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.2.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.2.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.2.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.1.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.1.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.1.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.1.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.1.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.9 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.8 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.13 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.12 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.11 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.10 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>       - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit ~6.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[6.0.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.10, 6.0.11, 6.0.12, 6.0.13, 6.0.2,
>   6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.8, 6.0.9, 6.1.0, 6.1.1, 6.1.2, 6.1.3, 6.1.4, 6.2.0, 6.2.1, 6.2.2, 6.2.3, 6.2.4, 6.3.0, 6.3.1, 6.4.0, 6.4.1, 6.4.2, 6.4.3, 6.4.4, 6.5.0, 6.5.1, 6.5.10, 6.5.11, 6.5.12, 6.5.13, 6.5.2, 6.5.3, 6.5.4, 6.5.5, 6.5.6, 6.5.7, 6.5.8, 6.5.9].
>
> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini
>   files:
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
>
> You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are
>   used by PHP in CLI mode. root@DESKTOP-T0FHR6I:/mnt/c/xampp/htdocs#

Comment: Which "instruction"? What step of the instruction did you hit this error?

Comment: From getcomposer.org "install for Linux". I installed Composer correctly but there was a problem with creating new laravel project.

Answer (score 3):

You can allow composer to run as root by copy and paste this line into your terminal:

```
export COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
```

Becasue running composer as root is not advisable, try to use this option with caution

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the error message, `phpunit` package requires `ext-dom` PHP extension to be installed. You should rather install `ext-dom` extensions or run composer with `--ignore-platform-reqs` flag:

```
composer create-project --ignore-platform-reqs --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

You can find explanation of this flag in [official composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project):

> **--ignore-platform-reqs**: ignore `php`, `hhvm`, `lib-*` and `ext-*` requirements and force the installation even if the local machine does not fulfill these.

Comment: I tried to push vote up but I need reputation more than 15. But now I have another problem. When I try to serve project I have something like that: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in /mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php on line 388

Comment: @roberto23 that's because you're running latest version of Laravel (which requires to have PHP 7.1) on a server with PHP 7.0. You need to upgrade your PHP version or to use previous version of Laravel

Comment: The line you have error on ([Arr.php on line 388](https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/master/Arr.php#L388)) is using feature called [array destruction](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.symmetric-array-destructuring) which was introduced in PHP 7.1

Comment: I tried upgrade by command: sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl php7.1-xml php7.1-zip php7.1-gd php7.1-mysql php7.1-mbstring but I still have 7.0.32 I tried some other commands too. BTW I use bash on ubuntu on windows

Comment: @roberto23 Try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/856793/upgrade-to-the-specific-php-7-1-7-2-from-php-7-0-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Thank you, I actually found this few minutes ago and finally It's working :)

Comment: @roberto23 You mark it as complete instead voting for the answer.